# What's the difference between let and const to loop through a collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Using Node.js (ES6) to loop through each object in a collection such as the one below:

```js
var statuses = [{
    statusId: 1,
    description: 'New'
  },
  {
    statusId: 2,
    description: 'Pending'
  },
  {
    statusId: 3,
    description: 'Approved'
  },
  {
    statusId: 4,
    description: 'Inactive'
  }
];
```

what is the difference between using:

```js
for (const status of statuses) {
  console.log(status.description);
}
```

and

```js
for (let status of statuses) {
  console.log(status.description);
}
```

The output is identical - is there anything going on under the hood that I should be aware of?

Comment: No difference, so `const` is preferable. `for` is considered a block scope.

Comment: @estus can you explain why `const` is preferable if they are identical?

Comment: Const is used when the variable is not changed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: Because it prevents from accidental reassigns of `status` inside `for` block (this is the reason why we have `const` at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With let, the following is possible - status can be reassigned:

```
var statuses = [
  {statusId:1, description: 'New'},
  {statusId:2, description: 'Pending'},
  {statusId:3, description: 'Approved'},
  {statusId:4, description: 'Inactive'}  
];

for (let status of statuses) {
    status = {statusId:1, description: 'New'};
    console.log(status.description);
}
```

However the same is not possible with const. If you do not want to accidentally reassign, const is preferable.

Comment: but you could still do `status. statusId = 111` meaning change the contents of each object, just not the reference to the object itself

Comment: true, you can always go a step further and specify member variable's accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

`let` is block scope declaration. definition/reference is limited to the block of its scope.

`const` is used when you want to fix the reference of your declaration to a primitive or object or an array. However is object or array is used, values inside it can still change.

If you do not want to accidentally reassign, const is preferable.